Integral of top chern class not giving Euler characteristic
Consider the two-sphere with radius $\rho$, denoted $S^2(\rho)$, with metric
\begin{align*} g_{ij} = \rho^2 \left(\begin{matrix} \sin^2\phi & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{matrix} \right)\end{align*} and set $\rho=1$. (For me, $\theta$ is azimuthal and $\phi$ is angle of declination from the north pole, $N$). Then the Christoffel symbols come out as
$$\Gamma_{\theta\theta}^\theta = 0, \Gamma_{\theta\phi}^\theta=\Gamma_{\phi\theta}^\theta=\frac{\cos\phi}{\sin\phi}, \Gamma_{\phi\phi}^\theta=0,$$
$$\Gamma_{\theta\theta}^\phi = \sin\phi\cos\phi, \Gamma_{\theta\phi}^\phi=\Gamma_{\phi\theta}^\phi=0, \Gamma_{\phi\phi}^\phi=0.$$ Let $\{\partial_\theta, \partial_\phi\}$ denote an ordered basis for the tangent space of each point of $S^2(\rho)$. Then using the convention from Griffiths-Harris for Chern classes, the connection matrix $\theta_{ij}$ is given by $$D e_i = \sum \theta_{ij} \otimes e_j$$ for $e_1, \dots, e_n$ an ordered basis for the coordinate frame $U_\alpha$. (I am just working over the open set $U = S^2 \setminus N$). Then we have
$$\nabla_X e_i = \sum \theta_{ij}(X) \otimes e_j $$
$$\nabla_X \partial_\theta = d\theta \cdot ( \Gamma_{\theta\theta}^\theta \partial_\theta + \Gamma_{\theta\theta}^\theta \partial_\phi) + d\phi \cdot( \Gamma_{\phi\theta}^\theta \partial_\theta + \Gamma_{\phi\theta}^\phi \partial_\phi )$$
and
$$ \nabla_X \partial\phi = d\theta( \Gamma_{\theta\phi}^\theta \partial_\theta + \Gamma_{\theta\phi}^\phi \partial_\phi) + d\phi( \Gamma_{\phi\phi}^\theta \partial_\theta + \Gamma_{\phi\phi}^\phi \partial_\phi).$$
Arranging $\theta_{ij}$ into the connection matrix $A$ gives
$$A = \left( \begin{array}{cc} \frac{\cos\phi}{\sin\phi} d\phi & -\sin\phi\cos\phi d\theta \\ \frac{\cos\phi}{\sin\phi}d\theta & 0 \end{array} \right) $$
$$dA = \left(\begin{array}{cc} 0 & (-\cos^2\phi + \sin^2\phi) d\phi \wedge d\theta \\ -\csc^2\phi d\phi \wedge d\theta & 0 \end{array} \right) $$
and
\begin{align*}
A \wedge A &=  \left( \begin{array}{cc} \frac{\cos\phi}{\sin\phi} d\phi & -\sin\phi\cos\phi d\theta \\ \frac{\cos\phi}{\sin\phi}d\theta & 0 \end{array} \right) \wedge  \left( \begin{array}{cc} \frac{\cos\phi}{\sin\phi} d\phi & -\sin\phi\cos\phi d\theta \\ \frac{\cos\phi}{\sin\phi}d\theta & 0 \end{array} \right) \\
&= \left(\begin{matrix} 0 & -\cos^2 d\phi\wedge d\theta \\ \cot^2\phi d\theta \wedge d\phi & 0 \end{matrix}\right). \end{align*}
Note that $\cot^2\phi d\theta\wedge d\phi = -\cot^2\phi d\phi \wedge d\theta$. Now, following the conventions of Griffiths-Harris, $F=dA - A\wedge A$ (yes, that really is a minus sign in Maurer-Cartan) gives
\begin{align*}
F = \left( \begin{matrix} 0 & \sin^2\phi d\phi \wedge d\theta \\ 1\cdot d\phi \wedge d\theta & 0 \end{matrix}\right) \end{align*}
To form Chern classes, if we take $\det( 1 + \frac{i}{2\pi} F)$, then we get
\begin{align*}
c(T \mathbb{P}^1) &= \det \left( \begin{matrix} 1 & \frac{i}{2\pi} \sin^2\phi d\phi \wedge d\theta \\ \frac{i}{2\pi} d\phi \wedge d\theta & 1 \end{matrix} \right) \\
&= 1 - \frac{1}{4\pi^2} \sin^2\phi d\phi \wedge d\theta \end{align*}
so that $c_{top}T\mathbb{P}^1 = c_1T\mathbb{P}^1 = - \frac{1}{4\pi^2} \sin^2\phi d\phi \wedge d\theta $. However, when I integrate this over $\mathbb{P}^1$, then I get $\frac{1}{4}$ rather than "$ \int_\mathbb{P}^1 c_1 (T\mathbb{P}^1) = \chi(\mathbb{P}^1) = 2$" as I would expect.
So I am wondering why integrating the top Chern class over $\mathbb{P}^1$ in this setup does not give the Euler characteristic.
Perhaps one needs an orthonormal basis to find the connection matrix $A$?

For starters, you need a complex bundle to talk about Chern classes. So you have to work with this as a complex line bundle, not a real $2$-plane bundle. You can find this computation done in various posts on this site.

You can, of course, use the Levi-Civita connection to compute the Euler class, instead.

A celebratory answer, as we get from the convention $\nabla_X e_j = \sum \omega_i^j(X) e_i$ and $F = dA + A \wedge A$ the new connection matrix which is $A^T$ from the $A$ above (which I will now denote simply as $A$): that is, in the "usual" basis $\mathcal{B} = \{\partial_\theta, \partial_\phi\}$,
$$A = \left( \begin{matrix} \cot\phi d\phi & \cot\phi d\theta \\ -\sin\phi\cos\phi d\theta & 0 \end{matrix} \right) $$ so that
$$dA = \left(\begin{matrix} 0 & -\csc^2(\phi) d\phi \wedge d\theta \\ -\cos^2(\phi) + \sin^2(\phi) d\phi \wedge d\theta & 0 \end{matrix}\right) $$
and
$$ A \wedge A = \left( \begin{matrix} \cot\phi d\phi & \cot\phi d\theta \\ -\sin\phi\cos\phi d\theta & 0 \end{matrix} \right) \wedge \left( \begin{matrix} \cot\phi d\phi & \cot\phi d\theta \\ -\sin\phi\cos\phi d\theta & 0 \end{matrix} \right) $$
gives $$ F = dA + A \wedge A = \left( \begin{matrix} 0 & 1 d\theta \wedge d\phi \\ -\sin^2\phi d\theta \wedge d\phi & 0 \end{matrix}\right). $$
In the orthonormal basis $\tilde{B} = \{ \frac{\partial_\theta}{\sin\phi}, \partial_\phi \}$ we have that $\tilde{e}_1 = \frac{1}{\sin\phi}e_1, \tilde{e_2} = 1\cdot e_2$ gives the change-of-basis matrix $$ a = \left[ \begin{matrix} \frac{1}{\sin\phi} & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{matrix}\right]$$ to say $\tilde{e} = ea$ as row vectors. The curvature matrix transforms as $$ \tilde{\Omega} = a^{-1}\Omega a $$ gives
\begin{align*} \tilde{\Omega} &= \left( \begin{matrix} \sin\phi & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{matrix}\right) \left(\begin{matrix} 0 & 1 \\ -\sin^2\phi & 0 \end{matrix}\right) \left(\begin{matrix} \frac{1}{\sin\phi} & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{matrix}\right)  \\
&= \left( \begin{matrix} 0 & \sin\phi\\ -\sin\phi & 0 \end{matrix}\right) \otimes d\theta \wedge d\phi \end{align*}
whose Pfaffian is
\begin{align*}
Pf(\tilde{\Omega}) &= \frac{1}{2} ( \tilde{\Omega}_{1,2} - \tilde{\Omega}_{2,1} )\\
&= \frac{1}{2} ( \sin\phi - (-\sin\phi) ) = \sin\phi \end{align*} tensored with $d\theta \wedge d\phi$ gives
\begin{align*}
\int_{S^2} Pf(\frac{1}{2\pi} \tilde{\Omega}) &= \int_{S^2} e[TS^2] \\
&= \int_{S^2} \frac{\sin\phi}{2\pi}d\theta \wedge d\phi\\
&= \frac{1}{2\pi} 2(2\pi) = 2 = \chi(S^2) \end{align*}
